# How to get email permission during facebook login android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nullpointerexception

I am building an android application where I am using facebook login. The code work very fine when there is facebook application installed in my phone.
Now the problem is that when there is no facebook application installed in my phone then the app crush on retrieving the mail ID.

Here is my fb login code -

onCreateView -

```
loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {

                // getting name of the user
                name = user.getName();

                // getting email of the user
                email = user
                        .getProperty("email")
                        .toString();

                // getting gender of the user
                id = user.getId();

                URL image_value = null;
                try {
                    image_value = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                profile_pic_url = image_value.toString();


                Intent gps = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS.class);

                // store string value
                editor.putString("fblogout", "1"); // Storing string
                editor.putString("name", name); // Storing string
                editor.putString("mail_id", email);
                editor.putString("id", id);
                editor.putString("profile_pic_url", profile_pic_url);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(gps);

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

onSession Open -

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                 Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        buttonsEnabled(true);



    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        buttonsEnabled(false);

    }
}
};

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null) {
        return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    } else
        return false;
}

public void requestPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null)
        s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, PERMISSIONS));
}
```

Error log -

```
    at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:283)
at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1668)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what does your error log say

Comment: Updating the question with the error log

Comment: cannot figure it out buddy. But I followed the offical implementation and it worked fine with or without app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2